# about feedback page

Tags: asp.net

I want to do a Feedback page what is the right way save the data 1.database 2. xml ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a database to store that information.

Answer (score 0):

Preferably you should use a database to store the information.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider integration with [**UserVoice**](http://uservoice.com/).
They offer a free core package.